# User prompt values not stored in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop

Fairly new to programming. I've set up a prompt command to have the user input text or a number which is stored to an array, but the while loop seems to be rewriting over the array value each time it loops.

The array is acting like a variable only storing one value

```
var course = new Array();
var grade = new Array();



while(confirm("Would you like to add a course?"))

    {course = prompt("Enter the course code. Example - ABC1234");
```

Answer (score 2):

To add an element to an array, use [`array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Change the last line to look like this:

```
course.push( prompt("Enter the course code. Example - ABC1234") );
```

You also have a missing `}` at the end. So your entire code snippet looks like this:

```
var course = new Array();
var grade = new Array();



while(confirm("Would you like to add a course?")){
    course.push( prompt("Enter the course code. Example - ABC1234") );
};
```

Comment: Cheers mate, but now the program is running weirdly. I've got the course array aswell as a grade array. below it are if functions making sure it meets certain conditions, slicing the array, checking the value length etc & now it throw up a false since I added the .push

Comment: I understand your concerns, but it's usually better to open a new question if the original one is answered. It helps other people (who will get your question by using search) to navigate SO more efficiently. And it helps you as well, too. )

Comment: @user1638050 You should add a new question as said above and give us a link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215413/array-push-causes-program-to-have-errors new question :)

Comment: @user1638050 I think you should really take a tutorial on using JS before jumping into making a web app (even if it's this simple).

Comment: Im taking a course in Javascript at my uni mate, this is my 2nd assignment, Im just stuck on getting user prompt values added to the array.

Comment: Ah. Either they didn't teach you about how arrays work at all, or you skipped a class or two. :P

Comment: I know how to setup an array with a predetermined Value, but this program doesn't have a max amount of indexes. The user could enter 1 or 100

Comment: I know, I know, and that's the beauty of a dynamic language. You don't need to allocate memory or anything of that sort. Best of luck!