# Array.push causes program to have errors

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, push, prompt

I followed the advice from a previous question to get my promps to add values to an array, but it has caused my program to throw up True values when they are not.

```
HIGHEST_GRADE = 7;
LOWEST_GRADE = 0;

var course = new Array();
var grade = new Array();

while(confirm("Would you like to add a course?")){
    course.push( prompt("Enter the course code. Example - ABC1234") );
};

var upperTest = course.slice(0,3);
var integerTest = course.slice(4,7);

if (course.length !== 7) {
    alert ('Invalid Course Code');
}

if (upperTest !== upperTest.toUpperCase()) {
     alert ('Invalid Course Code');
}

if (isNaN(integerTest)) {
    alert('Invalid Course Code'); 
}

if (isNaN(grade)) {
    alert('Invalid Grade');
}

if (LOWEST_GRADE > grade || HIGHEST_GRADE < grade) {
    alert('Invalid Grade');
}
```

I have it set to make sure the entered text matches the conditions, but since the .push was added the whole thing stuffs up.

I get an Invalid Course Code error, something is playing up with that.

Comment: What is your question? How is it failing?

Comment: It throws up the Invalid course code, as if its giving it a true value when it should be false.

Answer (score 1):

The `Array` is used to store multiple courses, which is fine. But, since it's an array, you need to access each position of it to validate each *individual* course, using a loop:

```
var courses = new Array();  // use the name courses instead, to indicate that it's a collection

for (var i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
  var course = courses[i];

  var upperTest = course.slice(0,3);
  var integerTest = course.slice(4,7);

  if (course.length !== 7) {
    alert ('Invalid Course Code');
  }

  if (upperTest !== upperTest.toUpperCase()) {
    alert ('Invalid Course Code');
  }

  if (isNaN(integerTest)) {
    alert('Invalid Course Code'); 
  }
}
```

This will validate every `course` that is in the `Array`. Otherwise, when you test `courses.length`, you'll be validating the number of elements in the array, *not* the number of characters of each course.

The same needs to be done for the `grades` array.

Comment: @raina77ow: Indeed, thanks, I don't see where OP is adding elements to that array, but I'll make a note.

Comment: Tried this & I am no longer getting any error messages when I deliberately disobey the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to validate entered course code? In such case you need to do it with the item not with the whole array:

```
while (confirm("...")) {
  var courseCode = prompt("...");

  var upperTest = course.slice(0,3);
  var integerTest = course.slice(4,7);

  if (courseCode.length !== 7) {
    alert ('Invalid Course Code');
    continue;
  }

  // place your other if's here

  courses.push(courseCode);
}
```